# Logically seperate azure kubernetes deployments

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a kubernetes cluster created and deployed with app.

First if I deployed with firstapp.yaml which created a pod and a service to expose the pod externally .

If i have two nodes in the cluster and then make another deployment with secondapp.yaml .

I noticed ,that the second deployment went to different node. Although this is desired behaviour for logical seperation .

Is it something that's provided by kubernetes. How will it manage deployments made using different files? will they always go on seperate nodes (if there are nodes provisioned) ?

If not, what is the practice to be followed if i want logical seperation between two nodes which i want to behave as two environments  , let's say dev and qa environment.

Answer (score 1):

No, they will not necessary go to different nodes. Scheduler determines where to put the  pod based on different criteria.

As for your last question - it makes no sense. You can use namespaces\network policies to separate environments, you shouldn't care on which node(s) your pods are. Thats the whole point of having a cluster.

You can use placement constraints to achieve what you ask for, but it makes no sense at all.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/

Comment: how do namespaces help ?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @4c74356b41. 
As an addition. It does not matter where your pods are, you can have multiple replicas of your application split between say 50 nodes, they can still communicate with each other (services, service discovery, [network CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/)) and share resources etc.

And yes, this is a default behavior of Kubernetes, which you can influence by taints, toleration's, resources, limits Node affinity and anti-affinity (you can find a lot of information about each of those in documentation or simply googling it). Also where the Pods are scheduled is dependent on Node [capacity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#node-capacity). Your pod has been set to a particular Node because Scheduler calculated it had best score, first taking into account mentioned conditions. You can find details about the process [here](https://medium.com/@dominik.tornow/the-kubernetes-scheduler-cd429abac02f).

Again as @4c74356b41 mentions, if you want to split your cluster into multiple environments, lets say for different teams or as you mention for dev and qa environments you can use [namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#when-to-use-multiple-namespaces) for that. They are basically making a smaller clusters in your cluster (note that this is more of a logical separation and not a separation from security perspective, until you add other components like 
for example roles) 
You can just add a `namespace` field to your deployment YAML to specify into which namespace you want to deploy your pods - still does not matter on which nodes they are. Depending on your use case.

Please note that what I wrote is oversimplified and I didn't mention many things in between, which you can easily find in most Kubernetes tutorials.